# How to replace all occurances of string pattern with number matching the string that depends on the order the strings were found

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need a bash script that searches for any string inside `<>`, if it finds one that it hasn't found before it should replace it with the current value of the index counter (0 at the beginning) and increment the counter. If it finds a string inside `<>`that it already knows, it should look up the index of the string and replace it with the index. This should be done across multiple files, meaning the counter does not reset when multiple files are searched for the patterns, only at program startup

file_a.txt:

```
<abc>
<b>
<c>
<c>
<abc>
```

file_b.txt:

```
<c>
<b>
```

Should become

file_a.txt:

```
0
1
2
2
0
```

file_b.txt:

```
2
1
```

What I got so far:

```
names=()
for file in folder/*.txt
do
    name=$(sed 's/\<[a-zA-Z]*\> /\1 /' file)
    for i in "${names[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$i" -eq "$name" ]
        then
            #replace string with index of string in array
        else
            names+=("$name")
        fi
    done
done
```

Edit:
What I did not mention in order to simplify the problem is that the patterns that should be replaced is not the only text inside the files, meaning the files look like this:
file_a.txt:

```
123abc<abc>xyz
efg
<b>ah
a<c>
<c>b
c<abc>
```

file_b.txt:

```
xyz<c>xyz
xyz<b>xyz
```

Should become

file_a.txt:

```
123abc0xyz
efg
1ah
a2
2b
c0
```

file_b.txt:

```
xyz2xyz
xyz1xyz
```

Because the files can be quite big, they should not be copied, only edited. This should be done for all files inside an folder and files in subfolders

Comment: Note that it's impossible to parse XML files with regex. `sed` is a wrong tool for this, use something smarter, like `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this awk script:

```sh
mkdir -p tmp

awk 'match($0, /<[^>]+>/) {
   k = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
   if (!(k in freq))
      freq[k] = n++
   $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) freq[k] substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
{
   print $0 > ("tmp/" FILENAME)
}' file_{a,b}.txt
```

Modified files will be saves in `tmp/` directory and you can move them back after examining their content.

```
cat tmp/file_a.txt

123abc0xyz
efg
1ah
a2
2b
c0

cat tmp/file_b.txt

xyz2xyz
xyz1xyz
```

Comment: Hey, what would I have to change if there can be multiple of these <X> in one line?

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab: This answer was written based on the sample data you provided initially and your edit. Handling multiple `<X>` will require substantial changes, please post a new question for that.

Comment: @anubhava https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024964/awk-script-for-replacing-multiple-occurances-of-string-pattern-in-the-same-line