# awk script for replacing multiple occurances of string pattern in the same line in different files with number matching the string

Tags: awk

I need a awk script that searches for any string inside <>, if it finds one that it hasn't found before it should replace it with the current value of the index counter (0 at the beginning) and increment the counter. If it finds a string inside <> that it already knows, it should look up the index of the string and replace it with the index. This should be done across multiple files, meaning the counter does not reset when multiple files are searched for the patterns, only at program startup
For example:
file_a.txt:

```
123abc<abc>xyz
efg
<b>ah
a<c>, <abc>
<c>b
(<abc>, <b>)
```

file_b.txt:

```
xyz(<c>, <b>)
xyz<b>xy<abc>z
```

should become

file_a_new.txt:

```
123abc<0>xyz
efg
<1>ah
a<2>, <0>
<2>b
(<0>, <1>)
```

file_b_new.txt:

```
xyz(<2>, <1>)
xyz<1>xy<0>z
```

What I got so far:

```
awk 'match($0, /<[^>]+>/) {
   k = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
   if (!(k in freq))
      freq[k] = n++
   $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) freq[k] substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
{
   print $0 > (FILENAME ".tmp")
}' files
```

But this can only detect one <> pattern per line, but there can be multiple <> patterns per line. So how should I change the code?

Edit:
The files should not be editet, instead new files should be created

Comment: Your samples are not looking correct. For line `123abc<abc>xyz` has `0` for `<abc>` and line `(<abc>, <b>)` also has `0` in it(shouldn't line `(<abc>, <b>)` have `1` in it?) , could you please explain more on it in your question?

Comment: Because <abc> was the first pattern found, all occurances of <abc> should be replaced with 0

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab if you are using GNU AWK, `match` has a third optional parameter, which is an array containing all matches. Perhaps that would be an approach?

Comment: It does correctly match all types of patterns, but once it found one in a line it moves to the next line without looking for more patterns in the same line

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab, Sorry but logic is still not clear(at least to me), if you could explain it more it will make question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` it is easier this way using `RS` as `<key>` string:

```
awk -v RS='<[^>]+>' '{ ORS="" }  # init ORS to ""
RT {                                        # when RT is set
   if (!(RT in freq))                       # if RT is not in freq array
      freq[RT] = n++                        # save n in freq & increment n
   ORS="<" freq[RT] ">"                     # set ORS to < + n + >
}
{
   print $0 > ("/tmp/" FILENAME)
}' file_{a,b}.txt
```

Comment: I know I've written that the change should be inplace, but could you modify the code so that it creates a new file?

Comment: This removes the pattern but does not replace it with the number

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR == 1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME ".tmp"
}
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/<[^>]+>/) ) {
        tgt = substr(tail,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        if ( !(tgt in map) ) {
            map[tgt] = cnt++
        }
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART) map[tgt]
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
    }
    print head tail > out
}
```

```
$ head file_*.tmp
==> file_a.txt.tmp <==
123abc<0>xyz
efg
<1>ah
a<2>, <0>
<2>b
(<0>, <1>)

==> file_b.txt.tmp <==
xyz(<2>, <1>)
xyz<1>xy<0>z
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct output, because the counter should not reset for every new file, instead it should have the same counter across all files.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the shell loop one will reset it, I'll fix that. Meanwhile - can you use the GNU awk one with `-i inplace`?

Comment: No, "awk: not an option: -i"

Comment: OK, I see you commented under a different answer that you actually do not want to modify the original files anyway - that makes thins simpler. Please update your question to reflect that change in your requirements.

Comment: I updated my answer to suit your new requirements.